# How can I expand a Gtk.Scale in a Gtk.ListBox

Tags: gtk3, pygobject

I would like to expand the Gtk.Scale widgets (they are inside a Gtk.ListBox) and get rid of the indentation of the bottom two. The indentation seems to be connected to the length of the text in the left column.

[image]

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3

    from gi.repository import Gtk
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3agg import FigureCanvasGTK3Agg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3 import NavigationToolbar2GTK3 as NavigationToolbar
    from numpy import pi

    window = Gtk.Window()
    window.set_default_size(800, 500)
    window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

    boxvertical = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    window.add(boxvertical)

    toolbar = Gtk.Toolbar()
    context = toolbar.get_style_context()
    context.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)
    boxvertical.pack_start(toolbar, False, True, 0)

    horizontalbox = Gtk.Box()
    boxvertical.pack_start(horizontalbox, True, True, 0)

    listcontainer = Gtk.Box(spacing=5)
    horizontalbox.pack_start(listcontainer, False, True, 0)

    listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
    listbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)
    listcontainer.pack_start(listbox, False, False, 5)

    def amplitude_changed(event):
        print(amplitude_scale.scale.get_value())

    def wavelength_changed(event):
        print(wavelength_scale.scale.get_value())

    row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
    listcontainer = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=100)
    row.add(listcontainer)
    label = Gtk.Label("<b>Settings</b>", xalign=0.5)
    label.set_use_markup(True)
    listcontainer.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)
    listbox.add(row)

    class ListBox():
        def __init__(self, name, lower_range, upper_range):
            self.name = name
            self.lower_range = lower_range
            self.upper_range = upper_range
            # two adjustments (initial value, min value, max value,
            # step increment - press cursor keys to see!,
            # page increment - click around the handle to see!,
            # page size - not used here)
            #self.adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment(0, 0, 20, 
            self.row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
            self.listcontainer = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=100)
            self.row.add(self.listcontainer)
            self.label = Gtk.Label(self.name, xalign=0)
            self.scale = Gtk.Scale()
            self.scale.set_range(self.lower_range, self.upper_range)
            #self.scale.set_hexpand(True)
            self.listcontainer.pack_start(self.label, False, False, 0)
            self.listcontainer.pack_start(self.scale, True, True, 0)
            listbox.add(self.row)

    amplitude_scale = ListBox("Amplitude", 0.0, 5.0)
    amplitude_scale.scale.connect("value-changed", amplitude_changed)
    wavelength_scale = ListBox("Wavelength", 0.0, 20.0)
    wavelength_scale.scale.connect("value-changed", wavelength_changed)
    displacement_scale = ListBox("Displacement", 0.0, 10.0)

    row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
    listcontainer = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=100)
    row.add(listcontainer)
    label = Gtk.Label("Color", xalign=0)
    combo = Gtk.ComboBoxText()
    combo.insert(0, "0", "Red")
    combo.insert(1, "1", "Green")
    combo.insert(2, "2", "Blue")
    listcontainer.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)
    listcontainer.pack_start(combo, True, True, 0)
    listbox.add(row)

    fig = Figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi=80)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    horizontalbox.pack_start(canvas, True, True, 0)

    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your self.listcontainer inside ListBox class should have the property:

```
    self.listcontainer.set_property ("homogeneous", True)
```